# How to Edit Source Files Directly in Chrome ?( and keep it after refresh)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

*After reading [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/) which suppose to help with my question ( but didn't) - I still have a question .*

Ok . My goal is to be able to edit downloaded scripts and keep the edit ! ( for next refresh).

Now i'm aware that it might wont work if a new timestamp is added to the file. but within my testing - the url is the exact name.

Say jQuery.com :

It downloads a script name `main.js` :

[image]

I click to edit it in the right pane ,  :

[image]

Then I save it ( notice the pink background).

I also save it in the desktop ( so it will be saved to a file system , as the article states)

But : when I refresh the page ( `f5` , not `ctrlf5`) - I get a fresh copy without my modifications :

[image]

**Question**

What am  I doing wrong ? and how can I make my modifications to stay even after refresh ?

(and besides if it shows the pink background-color as a saved , file .... saved where ? why the changes are not saved ")

nb : chrome ver 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: You need to modify source file.

Comment: @LIUFA you mean the html ?

Comment: in this case main.js, what you are doing would be equivalent of writing to console window `var x = '20'; alert(x);`

Comment: @LIUFA Am I not doing it already ?

Comment: You're not, you are modifying DOM but the moment you refresh the page they are gone, what you want is to modify source

Comment: @LIUFA so **how** can I do it ? can you please show picture or something ?

Comment: Open the file you downloaded (main.js) in notepad, add alert(1); click CTRL+S. then in chrome CRTL+F5.

Comment: @LIUFA Where the main.js is found ? I dont think i should search it via file system.... it is in one of the temp folders....

Comment: You need to write/find a browser extension or proxy server that will intercept your browser's request for the URL and replace the response with your file.

Comment: @Quentin So what does this "save" action do ?

Comment: Where the article mentions saving the file to the local file system, it means that it is saving the _source_ file of the viewed page. In other words, it is supposed to help you with development of _your_ website, not with saving your edits to other people their websites.

Comment: @RoyiNamir — It saves the edited code in a file.

Comment: @Quentin when I click save in the chrome sources via CTRL S , it changes the background-color to pink and now it is saved. it does ask me where to save it. so what file are we talking about ? I mean what can I do with this "saved" file ?

Comment: @gpgekko oh.... that's changes my whole POV about this feature .... tnx

Comment: @RoyiNamir — There is (1) a URL with the original code. There is (2) a copy of the code in memory that the browser uses to display the page. There is (3) a file with your saved code. You edit (2) and save it to (3). The only file is (3).

Comment: @Quentin do you know any chrome extension which can stripe code / files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, at `console` at jquery.api.com . Edit, or compose new pieces at `textarea`, click `refresh` to re-load original document , with edited, or newly composed pieces included.

i.e.g., `alert(1)` or `click` event, other pieces, composed at `textarea`, for re-loaded or "refreshed" document.

```
(function refresh() {
return $.get($("script").filter(function () {
        return (/main/.test(this.src) ? true : false);
    }).attr("src") || "http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-" 
    + "content/themes/jquery/js/main.js")
    .done(function (data) {
    $("<textarea id=edit class=edit style=width:480px;>")
    .val(data).appendTo("body");
    $("<input class=edit type=button value=refresh>")
    .appendTo("body");
    $("#edit").focus();
    })
    .always(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        $("input.edit").on("click", function (e) {
            var edit = $("textarea.edit").val();
            return $.get("", function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var refresh = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    refresh.write(data);
                    refresh.close();
                    $("html").find("script").filter(function () {
                        return (/main/.test(this.src) ? true : false);
                    }).remove();
                    $("<script type=text/javascript class=edit>")
                    .text(edit).prependTo("head");                
            });
        });
});
}())
```

Comment: Thank you but this won't help. I want that a script will be changed BEFORE it goes into my browser. ( in other words : " hey script.js - Royi has changed you so you should render as the NEW script and not as you oroginal written")_

Answer (score 6):

I think the critical point here is that the site you're editing needs to be served locally. Unless you're actually serving api.jquery.com from your own computer, your saved changes will be lost when you refresh.

You should save the files you're working on to your computer and open them in Chrome. Then follow the article's directions. When you right-click 'Save As', save it to the same place on disk that the file is being served from.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved a quite similar work flow using [this tutorial](http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/)

You can also use [Chrome's extension for autosave](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-autosave/mlejngncgiocofkcbnnpaieapabmanfl)

More detailed instructions can be found here: http://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave

*Note that you can edit your own files only, and that a server like setup is required*

Answer (score -1):

You are not doing anything wrong, as per my understanding.
I just want you to make sure that after you make changes in js file, and saving it, go to the directory where the JS file is placed. Open in some other text editor, say notepad or any other, and confirm if your changes are really saved.
Because when you hit refresh in browser, the served js file is picked.
There is no browser issue and also there ain't any process issue. 
I just doubt that changes made from browser are really getting reflected in file or not.
Please confirm once and also share across your observations.